# Div with arrow up on top of div and box positioning

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I am trying to make a popup with dropdown login effect,
but I’m having trouble with how I could get my arrow up on the div

like this:

[image]

but i got this:

[image]

And I also have trouble positioning my invisible div correctly below my menu

I used position absolute, but is not responsive in mobiles devices etc.

I would like help with the best way to position my element in the right way
 and how I would position my arrow correctly

code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isHover, setisHover] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(isHover);
  return (
    <>
      <LoginColumn>
        <WrapperLogin
          onMouseOver={() => setisHover(true)}
          onMouseOut={() => setisHover(false)}
        >
          <a>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              className="adjust"
              icon={faUserCircle}
              size="2x"
              fixedWidth
              color="white"
            />
          </a>
          <div>
            <a>
              <h3>Olá !</h3>
              <p>
                Minha Conta
                <span>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    className="adjust"
                    icon={faAngleDown}
                    size="lg"
                    fixedWidth
                    color="white"
                  />
                </span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </WrapperLogin>
        <SignWrap hover={isHover}>a</SignWrap>
      </LoginColumn>
    </>
  );
```

my css:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
export const SignWrap = styled.div`
  display: ${props => (props.hover ? "block" : "none")};
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  top: 100px;
  :before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #000;
    transform: rotate();
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  }
`;
export const LoginColumn = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
`;
export const WrapperLogin = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  :hover {
  }
  svg {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  h3 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: white;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
`;
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-matsumoto-mgy2q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is basically 2 things. Your positioning, and which border you're using for the arrow effect. So if you change your position to top / right, and allow top to place the pseudo element outside of the box, and swap border-top for border-bottom to flip your arrow, voila. Oh and most of the rest of the properties you have in there are innocuous. Have a great weekend!

Change;

```
:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #000;
    transform: rotate();
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  }
```

to;

```
    :before {
       content: "";
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       right: 1rem;
       top: -15px;
       border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
       border-left: 15px solid transparent;
       border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  }
```

Comment: what would innocuous property be?
What would be the best thing to do?

Comment: @MykonSpt just remove them like I did. They're just not necessary and do nothing towards your goal. :)

Comment: I understand you could help me how would I be able to position my svg icon in the same position as my arrow?

Comment: Well that's more involved, you currently have the parent at 40% so the position of the top arrow will not be consistent. If you change your layout to where you know what the distance will be reliably then you would just use the same distance to place where your popup arrow is. However it would require some refactoring and I do not know all your requirements. Maybe tinker with it and see if you can find something that works for you. :)

Comment: basically i'm using the display: flex

will I have to leave that aside and concentrate on using position absolute in this div?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just depends on how you genuinely expect it to behave while the window it's in gets resized and that 40% width changes. Welcome to the joys of front end development :D